# running trac as single enviroment, how do I get rid of "Available Projects" page?

Tags: svn, trac

I need trac to be 1 environment, so project selection page of trac is useless for my needs.

Is there any setting in trac.ini or using trac-admin to disable available projects selection page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such Trac option. And it is not needed to achieve, what you ask for.

Trac's organizational unit is the environment. The '-s' switch to *tracd* is a cheap redirect rule, to forward requests to the webserver root directory to another directory, the single Trac env. You can arrange the same with

- `Redirect /trac/ http://www.example.com/trac/single-env` in a [.htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525978) or httpd.conf
- Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) and a suitably edited .htaccess file with something like `RewriteRule ^trac$ /trac/single-env`

You shouldn't use available client-side redirects, because they are just unreliable.

Answer (score 2):

When you use [Tracd](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracStandalone#Reference), you can use the option --single-env;

```
-s, --single-env      only serve a single project without the project list
```

You can also set this in /etc/conf.d/tracd to TRACD_OPTS; for example

```
TRACD_OPTS="--single-env --auth=*,/var/lib/trac/myproject/users.htdigest,example.com /var/lib/trac/myproject"
```

Comment: I don't use Tracd, I run it off apache2. How do I do the same?

Comment: Possibly you can modify the [Project List Template](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInterfaceCustomization#ProjectList) and put a (javascript) redirect in it.

Comment: I don't know. Maybe wait until someone else replies. If you use apache, there also might be enough options in apache to do this, so there is no need for trac to implement this.